# c++ stl priority queue constructors

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

I wrote the following code to take in many inputs and then output them in a specific order.

```
#DEFINE cases 100     

struct job
{
int w;
};

class compjob
{
public:
       bool operator()( job j1,job j2)
       {
       if(j2.w>j1.w)
       return true;

       return false;
       }
};

int main()
{
priority_queue< job, vector<job>, compjob > jobs;

int weight;



for(int i=1;i<=cases;i++)
{
cin>>weight;
job job1;
job1.w=weight;

jobs.push(job1);
} //for loop ends here


for(int i=1;i<=cases;i++)
{
job job1= jobs.pop(); ////////////ERROR!!!!!/////////
cout<<job1.w<<endl;
}

return 0;;
}
```

But when I compile the code, a compile error is displayed on the line marked above:

```
Invalid conversion from 'void' to non scalar 'job'.
```

I think that I didn't declare jobs priority_queue correctly. Also, please explain the significance of second argument in the declaration(i.e. vector, I don't really know its use)

Comment: As an aside: Refactor all occurrences of `if (…) return true; else return false;` to `return …;`.

Comment: At first glance, did you forget to include `<queue>` ?

Comment: @billybob...I included <queue>, just didn't include the header section of my code here

Comment: @KonradRudolph...sorry...didn't get you?. Can you please explain?

Comment: oh... also it's better to replace "#DEFINE" with "#define".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[pop](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/pop/) does not return anything, use [top](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/top/) first to get the element and then pop it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend you to see the help page [C++ reference: priority_queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/top/) , everytime you're using a library.

Some guy might say cpluplus contains some errors, so you can try [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) as an alternative.